# Which is current correct indy and open ssl versions to use with delphi2007

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, delphi-2007

I'm using indy components with D2007 and try to list subject of messages from a imap mailbox. 
I downloaded and installed current indy new version 10.6.0.5039 (installing x100 packages) and tried with various openssl dll versions (32bit on xp machine, copied both in system32 dir and in my app dir) but always got "could not load ssl library" error. 
Could someone tell me the right indy dcl package and openssl dll to use with D2007?
Using function WhichFailedToLoad i get the result:
"SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy X509_get_notBefore_indy X509_get_notAfter_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy SSL_CTX_get_version_indy SSL_CTX_set_options_indy des_set_odd_parity des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt"

Answer (score 2):

Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit tells you why OpenSSL could not be loaded.

The latest snapshot of Indy 10 uses the latest version of OpenSSL.  There are OpenSSL DLLs available for download from Indy's Fulgan mirror:

http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Comment: Remy thanks for your reply, from function WhichFailedToLoad i get a lot of error values, and i still need response to my 2 questions:

Comment: Remy thanks for your reply, from function WhichFailedToLoad i get a lot of error values, and i still need response to my 2 questions: with my d2007 i compiled and installed indysystem100  dclindycore100  dclindyprotocols100 from fulgan indy10_5039.zip  and i copy ssleay32.dll and libssl32.dll from fulgan openssl-1.0.1e-i386-win32.zip that seems to be latest versions for indy e for ssl. Component TIdIMAP4 has utUseImplicitTLS option and component TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL has sslvTLSv1 method.

Comment: You should not be getting "a lot of error values".  If the DLLs cannot be loaded at all, only the filenames should be reported. If the DLLs are loaded, then only missing functions should be listed. If you are getting "a lot" of missing functions, then something is seriously wrong. Please update your question with the actual output from `WhichFailedToLoad()`.

Comment: Actual output from WhichFailedToLoad is "SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy X509_get_notBefore_indy X509_get_notAfter_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy SSL_CTX_get_version_indy SSL_CTX_set_options_indy des_set_odd_parity des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt"

Comment: The fact that there are `"..._indy"` functions listed tells me that you are trying to use newer OpenSSL DLLs with an OLD version of Indy. Early versions of Indy had to use custom-built OpenSSL DLLs that exported custom `"..._indy"` functions to access private OpenSSL data that has since been publically exposed in later OpenSSL versions.  Modern Indy releases (especially 10.6.0) use standard OpenSSL DLLs. So this tells me that your app is NOT using Indy 10.6, like you claim, but is in fact using Indy 9 or earlier. Those custom Indy OpenSSL DLLs are available in Fulgan's `SSL\Archive` folder.

Comment: Many thanks, Remy. I apologize for my error. I deinstall previous versions of Indy and install new version but not remove all dirs and delphi environment has a path to old Indy10 lib, i see new components and link old.

Comment: How about OSX where I can get one for this platform ?

Comment: @Wel Apple has deprecated all support for OpenSSL in iOS and OSX. In OSX High Sierra, OSX now uses LibreSSL, which is a fork of OpenSSL. [Indy does not natively support LibreSSL](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/231). You will have to obtain OpenSSL dylibs through other means, such as Homebrew. Also [see this discussion](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,42598.msg297598) and in particular [this message](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,42598.msg297525.html?PHPSESSID=h5gjsbi7gq1q61a4mnjluoq5p1#msg297525) for ideas.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just noticed the nethttp component can I use it instead on Mac OSX ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Where I can find you now ? which forum or you are only at SO ?

Comment: @Wel not just on StackOverflow, but also at the Embarcadero Community Forums, AToZed forums, Delphi Praxis forums, and BCBJ forums.